# Create a temporary directory for specific steps in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a Jenkins pipeline step that will create and run a block of steps in a directory?

I know that the `dir` step runs the steps in the block in a specific directory:

```java
// not in /tmp/jobDir
dir ('/tmp/jobDir') {
    // these steps get run in /tmp/jobDir
}
// once again not in /tmp/jobDir
```

My question is if there is a step in Pipeline or in a plugin that let's me run this codeblock, but `/tmp/jobDir` is created at the start of the block, and is removed at the end of the block.

Something like:

```java
// /tmp/jobDir does not exist
dir ('/tmp/jobDir') {
    // /tmp/jobDir now exists
    // these steps get run in /tmp/jobDir
}
// /tmp/jobDir has been removed
```

Does such a step or plugin exist?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not exactly. There's the [`deleteDir` step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-deletedir-code-recursively-delete-the-current-directory-from-the-workspace), which deletes the current directory, so you could do:

```groovy
dir('/tmp/jobDir') {
    // your steps here
    deleteDir()
}
```

If this comes up often enough, you could also just make your own function:

```groovy
def tempDir(path, closure) {
    dir(path) {
        closure()
        deleteDir()
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```groovy
tempDir('/tmp/jobDir') {
    // your steps here
}
```

---

**Edit**: If you only want to delete the directory if it was newly created, you can use [`fileExists`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-fileexists-code-verify-if-file-exists-in-workspace):

```groovy
def tempDir(path, closure) {
    def dirExisted = fileExists(path)
    dir(path) {
        closure()
        if(!dirExisted) {
            deleteDir()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the `dir` step create the directory if it doesn't already exist?

Comment: @jpyams Yes, it does

Comment: Note that if you do stuff in the directory, Jenkins will create a `/tmp/jobDir@tmp` directory, or sometimes a `/tmp/jobDir@script` directory. These have to be manually deleted (see [this issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41805))

Comment: For what it's worth, there's also a `pwd(tmp:true)` call that can generate a unique temporary directory.  So, to avoid temp dirs from colliding on the same node, you do: `dir(pwd(tmp:true)) { /* ... things ... */; deleteDir(); }`.

Comment: I can't say how hard I face palmed when I came across this page
https://newbedev.com/create-a-temporary-directory-for-specific-steps-in-jenkins-pipeline  Some people have no shame.

Answer (score 8):

My favorite solution so far:

```
withTempDir {
 // Do something in the dir,e.g. print the path
 echo pwd()
}

void withTempDir(Closure body) {
  // dir( pwd(tmp: true) ) { // Error: process apparently never started i
  dir( "${System.currentTimeMillis()}" ) {
    try {
      body()
    } finally {
      deleteDir()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

How about this to create a temp path and then use it via a dir clause.  It seems to work for me.

```
dir (pwd(tmp: true)) {...}
```

I'm not sure if this creates A temp directory or uses THE one and only temp directory for the workspace.  The [docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#dir-change-current-directory) say 'a' but seeing is believing.

Comment: Since calling `echo pwd('tmp': true)` twice returns same result, I assume it uses THE temp directory for the workspace, always.

Comment: Yes, it will always return the same temporary dir: the one of that workspace (${WORKSPACE}@tmp).

Comment: The temporary directory depends on the current working directory. If you dir() to somewhere else, `pwd(tmp:true)` returns another value.

Comment: Jenkins will not _always_ return the same directory. If you call `pwd(tmp: true)` from *inside* of a temporary directory, it'll add another `@tmp` on the end. So in other words, running `dir(pwd(tmp: true)) { dir(pwd(tmp: true)) {} }` will result in the inner directory being `$WORKSPACE@tmp@tmp`. This can lead to troubles with the workspace cleanup plugin, since it won't touch directories with `@tmp@tmp` (and beyond).